# Cross section of expected returns vs cross section of returns

Tags: asset-pricing, capm

Typically, one estimates the CAPM beta of stock $i$ of a time series regression of stock excess returns $R_t$ on the market excess return $MRP$:

$R_{t} = \alpha + \beta MRP_t + \epsilon_t$,

where $t$ denotes a period (i.e. month hereafter). The sample for this regression spans from $T-k$ up to $T$.

Repeated for different stocks $i$, one gets a cross section of betas $\beta_i$. According to e.g. [Bali et al. (2016), p.131](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Empirical+Asset+Pricing:+The+Cross+Section+of+Stock+Returns-p-9781118095041), the CAPM predicts that "there is a positive relation between market beta and expected stock returns, and the slope defining this relation represents the market premium". This relation is then, inter alia, tested by performing "a cross-sectional regression of one-month-ahead future excess stock ($R_{T+1}$) on the given measure" ([Bali et al. (2016), p.140](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Empirical+Asset+Pricing:+The+Cross+Section+of+Stock+Returns-p-9781118095041)), i.e. the CAPM beta:

$R_{i,T+1} = \gamma_1 + \gamma_2 \beta_{i} + \epsilon_{i,T+1}$.

Now my question is, how does one get from a theoretical model that involves expected returns (the first quote), to an empirical model that involves future realized returns (the second quote)? Those two concepts are completely different in my opinion.

Thank you in advance for clarifying.

Comment: I don't think you use next period returns - you use some (time-series) average return of asset $i$. Usually $i$ is a diversified portfolio of assets.

Comment: But what I described is exactly what e.g. Fama & French (1992) do. With the difference that they add other factors to the aforementioned regression. The time-lag between beta and return remains, though.

Comment: A few notes: A conditional CAPM might posit $\mathbb{E}_t[R_{i,t+1}^e]=\beta_{i,t}\lambda$, where $\lambda$ is the (constant) price of risk. The (monthly ) excess return is the realised (monthly) return less the interest rate over the same time period (month). Because it's risk-free, we assume that we know that risk-free rate in advance and often take it out of the expectation. Note that the CAPM makes no statement about $\lambda$ being significant. This is _not_ a test of the CAPM! Finally, future realised returns are the best (albeit bad) proxies for ex-ante expected returns.

Comment: @Kevin thank you. However, I am not sure why you are referring to a conditional CAPM, could you clarify? Also, why is this not a test of the CAPM? E.g. Bali et al. (2016) (Empirical Asset Pricing) state something like this many times: "the CAPM predicts that cross-sectional variation in the expected
returns of different securities is driven only by cross-sectional variation in the betas
of the securities (p.122)" or "The fundamental prediction of the
CAPM of Sharpe (1964), Lintner (1965), and Mossin (1966) is that there is a positive
relation between market beta and expected stock returns"

Comment: @Kevin also, at least in my opinion, current realised returns are a far more inutitive and logical proxy for ex-ante expected returns: I simply extrapolate into the future, instead of ... I do not even see an argument for using future realised returns, other than implying that the investors knew the realisation beforehand. But then, whats the point in doing all of this? Hence: why not use $R_{i,t}$ instead of $R_{i,t+1}$? The only argument I see is that it's somewhat of an out of sample test.

Comment: The only terms with time indices are $R$ and $\varepsilon$, and there is no lag between them. What time lag are you referring to? If you are thinking about $\beta$ (*the CAPM-beta is expected to predict the next period returns*), it does not have a time index, so the formula does not seem to match you verbal description.

Comment: Well, the standard CAPM is a one-period model, so there is no concern about the time indices because there is only one random variable (the future realised return). The CAPM tells us that stock returns line up with their beta. So what's the main prediction? $\alpha=0$! _That's_ the right test for a cross-sectional asset pricing model. The factor doesn't need to be prices itself. The theory doesn't require the market to have a positive premium.

Comment: The CAPM Is a one-period model, i.e. $\beta_i$ is _not_ the result of a time-series regression in theory. In practice, we us this regression to estimate $\beta$ because we have no other way of doing this. The future return shouldn't be part of the information we use to calculate cross-sectional predictors to avoid look ahead bias.

Comment: @RichardHardy you are right, I edited the first part of the post accordingly.

Comment: So what model exactly do you estimate on data ranging from $t-k$ to $t-1$?

Comment: I edited the question again. The question should be clearer now. Also @Kevin, the book I quote clearly states that there are \textbf{two} main predictions of the CAPM. 1) there exists a positive relation between expected returns and beta, 2) after accounting for beta, there is no average excess return left (this is what you are saying). You are saying that statement 1) is wrong if I understand you correctly? We can move this discussion to chat if you don't mind.

Comment: It is clearer now, thank you. A very minor thing: your sample is said to span from $t-k$ to $T$; you probably meant $T-k$, not $t-k$. Regarding expected returns vs. future realized returns: I think expectations are also about the future, not the current period (which is observed), and the realized value $r_{t+1}$ is an unbiased proxy for $\mathbb{E}(R_{t+1})$.

Comment: @RichardHardy alright I see. So asset pricing models are about expectations, not future returns, albeit future returns proxy for expecations. The fact that we use future returns as a proxy gives us insight into how predictable actual returns (not their expectations) actually are, as kind of a byproduct. Do I understand that correctly?

Comment: I do not have enough experience with CAPM to confirm or disconfirm your interpretation, sorry, and I do not want to mislead you.